# Python: Is there any difference between x[i,:] and x[i][:]

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I tried printing both of these:

```
print(X_train[0])
print(X_train[0,:])

#Output
[ 59.  62.  63. ... 123.  92.  72.]
[ 59.  62.  63. ... 123.  92.  72.]
```

I thought that these are same and so I tried this:

```
print(X_train[0,:3])
print(X_train[0][:3])

#Output
[59. 62. 63.]
[59. 62. 63.]
```

So are both of these `X_train[0,:3]` and `X_train[0][:3]` equivalent?

Comment: For numpy, yes, they are equivalent in output. Note that the first syntax is specifically numpy indexing; vanilla python does not operate in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equivalent in terms of the output yes, but in terms of what happens underneath the hood... no.

In the case of `X_train[0,:3]`, there is one `__getitem__` call to the array. In the second case, there is `tmp = X_train[0]` with one `__getitem__` call that returns a temporary array (usually a view into the original... your mileage may vary) followed by a subsequent `tmp[:3]` which is an additional `__getitem__` call—which isn't so much overhead, but if you can do it better, why do it worse?

Comment: Just one more thing to ask, so X_train[0] and X_train[0,:] are computationally equivalent as they both have to perform `__getitem__` call only once?

Comment: @subtleseeker one syntax is the simpler version of the other, so yes.